# How do I check if the result of an expression is NULL in HTML and if it is, display nothing?

Tags: html, kendo-ui

```
<script id="namesAutoCompleteTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">    
            <div class="k-widget k-grid" id="Grid">
            <div class="k-grid-content">
            <h3>${data.NameFirstInitLast}</h3>
            <p>Person ID: ${data.PersonId}</p>
            <p>Member Number: ${data.MemberNumber}</p>
            <p>Member Status: ${data.MemberStatus}</p>
            <p>Category: ${data.PrimaryCategoryCode}</p>
</script>
```

If the result of any of the expressions above (e.g. ${data.PersonId} = NULL, then display '' or nothing).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: couldn't you create a function that checks?  perhaps use the ternary operator `?` ..

Comment: Do you see NULL as string in your page or you don't see anything ?

Comment: I see "null" on the actual page.

Comment: What is ${...}? It's not HTML. Is this from a server-side template engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather from your `<script/>` tag that you are using a Kendo UI template? Therefore, the `#` character is used as an escape sequence in Kendo templates, so that you can insert JavaScript code to be evaluated by Kendo's templating engine. Here is an example of what you're probably looking to achieve:

```
<script id="namesAutoCompleteTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">    
  <div class="k-widget k-grid" id="Grid">
    <div class="k-grid-content">
      # if (data) { #
      <h3>${data.NameFirstInitLast}</h3>
      <p>Person ID: ${data.PersonId}</p>
      <p>Member Number: ${data.MemberNumber}</p>
      <p>Member Status: ${data.MemberStatus}</p>
      <p>Category: ${data.PrimaryCategoryCode}</p>
      # } #
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

On a side note, I'm not fond of the `${}` syntax, and Kendo is not very consistent with which of the three types of escape character sequences to use in their own documentation. I would suggest sticking with `#=data.property#` and/or `#:data.property#` as a matter of consistency. But, that's just my opinion. :)